# Buttons with Django to choose items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, button

I have 6 buttons which are options to buy something. You cannot make multiple choices but choose one and it automatically selects that item and reroutes you to checkout section. My question is, using Django, how do I embed the values of those buttons (ie. price, credits etc) into each button so they the ones used in the checkout. My initial method was that I created the items dynamically in Django.admin and instead of having a page in which you individually selected an item you had instead a checkboxes to select from whichever items I had created in the admin through a model (bono) I had created. However, I need the items to be hard coded into individual buttons rather than relying on Django.admin and the server.

I've attached a sample html and pic showing the buttons and will add any other items upon request. I simply had no clue which items I should include:
EDIT:
I am currently using a link tag to reroute to a different page but that does not post anything to the model.
The model for the packages is as follows:

```
class CreditPackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Credit Package Name')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 10000, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Description')
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Price')
    nr_credits = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Number of Credits:')
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank = False, verbose_name = 'On Sale:')
```

I need to make the circles, upon clicking, pass the relevant info to that model and the reroute to a checkout.

[image]
The html of one of the buttons only:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint">
              <a href="{% url 'student-packages' %}">
              <div class="circle" style="background: #0045ab" ><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;"  >3</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">25€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">5€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal if you want to<br>
                  try out Milingual {% endblocktrans %}</br>.
                </div></a>
            </div>
```

the full html of the page:

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block bonos %}
<div class="container" >
 <div id='titleb' class="container">
  <h2 style= "color:black; align=center">MILINGUAL BONO</h2>
 </div>
 <div id='titleb' class="container">
  <h1 style= "color:black; align=center">MILINGUAL BONO</h1>
 </div>

 <div>
 <p>{% trans 'The Milingual Bono offers you more classes for much lesser. It saves you the hasslse of pasying each time you book a class, at the same time offering you the flexibilty of attending any Milingual class or event, anytime you want. Pick the 3 class bono if you would like to give it a try firt or book the <b>season bono</b> for unlimited access for 3 months.' %}
 </p>
 </div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- New set of columns, centered -->
        <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal">
              <a href="{% url 'student-packages' %}">
              <div class="circle" style="background: #0045ab" ><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;"  >3</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">25€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">5€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal if you want to<br>
                  try out Milingual {% endblocktrans %}</br>.
                </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle" style="background: #58aeb4" ><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">6</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">39€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">21€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal if you want to<br>
                  try Milingual or have attended <br>
                  a couple of classes. {% endblocktrans %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle"   style="background: #e8bf16"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">8</span><br> Credits
                </div>
                <div class="ribbon-wrapper-blue">
                  <div class="ribbon-blue">{% trans 'Most Popular' %}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="price">50€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">30€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal if you want to practice <br>
                  twice a week for a month {% endblocktrans %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <span><br></span>
<div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- New set of columns, centered -->
        <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" >
              <div class="circle"  style="background: #a7a5a7"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">10</span><br>Credits
              </div>
                <div id="price">64€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">36€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal if you want to make<br>
                  Milingual part of your routine {% endblocktrans %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle"  style="background: #c6595b"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">12</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">79€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">41€</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Ideal for multiple classes per<br>
                  week. {% endblocktrans %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle2"   style="background: #b18358"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:50px;">SEASON</div>
                <div id="price">89€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">200€*</span><br><br>
                    {% blocktrans %} Get unlimited accee to <br>
                  classes as well as paid events<br>
                  for no extra cost. {% endblocktrans %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock bonos %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model (DataStorageModel in my example) that stores all of the info in your database and reference it by some name field.

put this name to your submit buttons with the name tag, e.g.:

```
<input id="create" type="submit" name="create" value="Create"/>
```

Then in your views.py check for the name in request.POST:

```
if request.POST.get('create'):
    obj = DataStorageModel.objects.get(name='create')
    ...
```

Update:

I just saw that you intend to store prices within a html tag. NEVER DO THAT! People can just change these values... Give as little as possible to the client. Therefore you need a model to store your prices etc.

```
DataStorageModel(model.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    credits = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

Comment: I am struggling to implement what you've described. How am I passing the individual values of each item? Creating a separate model for each item with the preset values or what? A more detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: and the redirect to the checkout I suppose is in the views?